# Error running karma with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am getting this error message when I execute the `karma start karma.conf.js`:

```
> throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
> ^ Error: No provider for "framework:requirejs"! (Resolving: framework:requirejs)
```

I have installed karma-cli globally and karma and jasmine locally.

This is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "bower": "^1.4.1"
        , "gulp": "^3.9.0"
        , "gulp-gjslint": "^0.1.4"
        , "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.0"
        , "gulp-jslint": "^0.2.2"
        , "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1"
    }
    , "devDependencies": {
        "karma": "^1.3.0"
        , "karma-cli": "^1.0.1"
        , "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0"
        , "jasmine": "^2.5.2"
        , "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2"
        , "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2"
        , "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0"
        , "requirejs": "^2.3.2"
    }
```

And the karma.conf.js has:

```
/*global module*/
module.exports = function (config) {
    'use strict';
    config.set({
        basePath: '', 
        frameworks: ['requirejs', 'jasmine'], 
        files: ['app/lib/angular/angular.js'
            , 'app/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
            , 'app/js/main.js'
            , 'app/test/testMain.js'], 
        exclude: [], 
        preprocessors: {}, 
        reporters: ['progress'], 
        port: 9876, 
        colors: true, 
        logLevel: config.LOG_DISABLE, 
        autoWatch: false, 
        browsers: ['Chrome'], 
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

I have tryed to install karma globally and this is not running too.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem deleting node_modules folder and following the next steps (installing packages in dev dependencies):

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install --save-dev karma
npm install --save-dev karma-cli
npm install --save-dev jasmine
npm install --save-dev jasmine-core
npm install --save-dev karma-jasmine
npm install --save-dev karma-chrome-launcher
npm install --save-dev requirejs
npm install --save-dev karma-requirejs
```